# How do I define the mass flow rate and the source term of the continuity equation when mass depends on the spatial coordinate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

I am studying fluid dynamics. I have questions regarding the mass flow rate and the continuity equation.

Consider the inviscid incompressible fluid flow through a pipe in various moments as illustrated in the picture below. Fluid mass enters the pipe in the $x$ direction at the left end of it, while the other end is closed.

[image]

From the above illustration, it is clear that mass flow rate $q$ is a scalar field that depends on time and space coordinates. The problem is, I found in literature that the mass flow rate is always dependent only on time, and it is defined as:

$$q(t) = {dm(t) \over dt} \tag 1$$

My question is, since in my illustration it is clear that the mass flow rate is dependent on the spatial coordinate, is the mass flow rate defined as:

$$q(t,x) = {dm(t,x) \over dt}={\partial m \over \partial x}{\partial x \over \partial t}+{\partial m \over \partial t}={\partial m \over \partial t} \tag 2$$

Or in other words, since the mass flow rate also depends on the spatial coordinate, is it now defined as a partial derivative of mass with respect to time instead of a total derivative of mass with respect to time? I assumed that ${\partial z \over \partial t}$ equals zero.

My next question is regarding the continuity equation. In the example I illustrated, there is a source at the left side of the pipe. So that means the continuity equation has a source term $S$:

$${\partial \rho \over \partial t} + \nabla (\rho {\vec v}) = S \tag 3$$

Since the fluid velocity $v$ depends on the time and space coordinate, the above equation can be reformulated as:

$$ \rho { \partial { v(x, t)} \over \partial x } = S(x, t) \tag 4$$

I do not understand how to define the source term. For example, let's say that in my example I know the mass flow rate function. Suppose that it is in the form:

$$ q(x, t) = (x - x_{max}) \sin(x-t) \tag 5$$

how would I define the source term S in this case? Also, if I only knew the mass flow rate at the beginning of the pipe:

$$ q(0, t) = \sin(t) \tag 6$$

would I be able to define the source term? If yes, how would I define it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption regarding the equation for mass flow rate is incorrect.  It is not defined as $\rho v A$, which is constant (unless there is a source).  With a source term, the integral of the continuity equation is $$(\rho v A)_x-(\rho v A)_0=A\int_0^x{Sdx}$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't really understand what you said. Are you saying that $ {dm(t,z) \over dt} -  {dm(t,0) \over dt}$ is equal to the RHS of your equation? I also still don't understand how to derive the source term if I know the mass flow rate at the inlet of the pipe. The incoming mass flow rate at the inlet changes with time.

Comment: dm/dt is not the mass flow rate .

Comment: Are you sure? It says here it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_flow_rate
But if it is not, then what is it?

Comment: Yes I’m sure.  I answered this in my answer.